# Subdomain for each shop Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento setup where vendors can create their shop.

Now I want that each shop will have their unique URL in the form of a sub domain.

For example if a vendor has created a shop which name is "abcshop" then URL for this shop should be http://abcshop.maindomain.com

Please help how we can achieve this.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow! This is now a specific Magento programming question, but rather regarding configuration, I would recommend posting it here - magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or, you can refer to step 16 onwards at the guide here - https://www.crucialhosting.com/knowledgebase/setup-multiple-magento-stores#adding-another-store-in-magento